# Merge after reverting the original merge

Tags: git

Alright I was inattentive when I was merging some code into a repository(There were major changes in the flow of some code), so I had to revert the merge commit. I went home for the day, and now there are more commits on master, and I can't seem to trigger a merge such that I can get my code into master, as in I have the diffs between the 2 files. I was clumsy and pushed to code to origin already.

Here's the one line graph history of the most recent commits:

[image: Commit History]

How do I get back a proper merge screen so that I can take care of it?

I was thinking I could add another commit to my branch then try to merge it, but that feels hackish.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand correctly. You have a branch, you merged it into master, then you reverted the code out of master. Now you're trying to merge the same branch into master again?

Comment: It's not clear what commits you want to keep and which ones your don't?

Comment: @mkasberg That's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When code is committed and then reverted on a branch, re-committing the same code will have no effect because of the original revert. For example, say you have one or more commits on branch `B`, and you revert them with commit `R`:

```
master
|
* R
|\
| * B
```

Merging `B` into master again will have no effect because git realizes that revert `R` happened *after* all the commits in `B` (even if `B` is merged again).

There are 2 possible solutions here.

#### Revert the Revert

One is to revert the revert (call this commit `R'`).

```
master
|
* R'
|
* R
|\
| * B
```

The command for this is simple. `$ git revert R`

---

#### Rebase the Branch

The other possible solution is to *rebase* the entire branch `B` so that it comes *after* the revert `R` (call the rebased branch `B'`). There are a few different variations of this, but they all depend on rewriting the branch history with new commits that are not present in the history of `R`.

```
master
| 
* New merge commit
|\
| * B'
|  \
|   ...
* R
|\
| * B
| ...
|/
* A
```

The commands for the rebase are as follows:

```
$ git checkout B
$ git rebase --no-ff A
```

Linus has some good [commentary](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) on this scenario for more reading.

Comment: How would I write the rebase line for this? Which branch would I work from when I'm rebasing it?

Comment: If you really do want to keep your original commits and want to merge them again, there is another option. You can install a temporary [graft](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) that hides the second parent of the merge commit. Then a `git merge` will merge the changes again. You need to know what you are doing, though, and remove the graft as soon as possible.